# Runtime Error; Address sanitizer:heap buffer overflow in leet code

Tags: c

I'm currently solving q.41 from leet code i.e. FIRST MISSING POSITIVE INTEGER. I've written the code in c but keep getting Address Sanitizer: heap buffer overflow error, no matter what changes i make to the data type. I would really appreciate some help because I'm stuck. Here is the program:

```
int firstMissingPositive(int* nums, int numsSize) {

for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < numsSize - i; j++) {
        if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
            int t = nums[j + 1];
            nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
            nums[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
int max = nums[numsSize - 1];
if (max <= 0) {
    return 1;
}
for (int k = 0; k < numsSize; k++) {
    if (nums[k] > 0) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int l = 1; l < max; l++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < numsSize; m++) {
                if (nums[m] == l)
                    c++;
            }
            if (c == 0)
                return l;
        }
    }
}
return max+1;
}
```

I've tried to run it in programiz compiler and it works there with a warning.

Comment: Install an actual local compiler. Enable the address sanitizer, the same way leetcode does it. Use your debugger to see where the problem happens.

Comment: Does the function ever get called with `numsSize` set to `0`?  If so, then the line `int max = nums[numsSize-1];` would be an out-of-bounds array reference that would likely make AddressSanitizer unhappy.

Comment: @Om Bhardwaj. "...  and it works there with a warning." --> what was the warning and why was not it fixed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code has a problem here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < numsSize - i; j++) {
        if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
```

In the first iteration of the outer loop `i` will be zero so the inner loop is the same as

```
    for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++) {  // When i equals zero
        if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
```

Consequently `j` will reach its maximum value as `numsSize-1`. Inserting that in the `if`statement gives:

```
        if (nums[numsSize-1] > nums[numsSize-1 + 1]) {  // When j equals numsSize-1
```

which is the same as

```
        if (nums[numsSize-1] > nums[numsSize]) {  // When j equals numsSize-1
```

and here `nums[numsSize]` is an out of bounds array access (assuming that `numsSize` represents the size of the array).